# Serializing a priority queue in scala

Tags: scala, serialization, priority-queue

I am trying to serialize a mutable `PriorityQueue` in scala (2.10) and am getting a `NotSerializableException` when writing the object to an ObjectOutputStream. I made a simple test case:

```
import java.io.{ByteArrayOutputStream, ObjectOutputStream}
import scala.collection.mutable

object Test extends App {
  val pq = new mutable.PriorityQueue[Int]()
  val oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new ByteArrayOutputStream())
  oos.writeObject(pq)
}
```

The exception is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.NotSerializableException:scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue$ResizableArrayAccess
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1180)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
at Test$.main(Test.scala:7)
```

It seems like a PriorityQueue should be serializable, is there something I can do to get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be reported as a bug - the fix is to simply make the nested `ResizableArrayAccess` class inherit `Serializable`.

Technically, maybe you could use reflection to remove the `private` and `final` modifiers on the `resarr` field in the priority queue class, then set it to `null` before serialization.

Otherwise, converting the priority queue to a, say, array before serialization and vice versa on deserialization would avoid this exception. You could roll in your own wrapper around the `PriorityQueue` to implement custom serialization/deserialization.

**Note**: This issue has been resolved in Scala 2.11.0-M7 ([SI-7568](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7568))

Comment: I'm now using custom serialization to convert to an array and back, I'll file a bug report as well. Thanks